Custom error handler without overwriting other handlers
I want to log errors to my own logging system, without interfering with other logging.
The following option is often suggested, but "error_get_last" no longer returns errors as soon as a custom handler is set with set_error_handler.
    register_shutdown_function(function () {
        $error = error_get_last();
        if ($error !== NULL) {
            echo "Shutdown error: [{$error['type']}] {$error['message']} in {$error['file']} on line {$error['line']}\n";
        }
    });

Is it possible to set a custom handler and not overwrite others?

In the manual it say: "It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_levels unless the callback function returns false". See: set_error_handler(). You could have tried harder to put some code in your question that reproduces the problem you say you are having. Now it's rather confusingly referring to both set_error_handler() and register_shutdown_function().

What's wrong with overwriting others tho? Are you talking of entire app or of a module/pacjage?

others? You can have only one error handler at any time.

Error and exception handlers are stacked and can be restored with restore_error_handler() and restore_exception_handler(). Honestly, I've never tried to do that inside an error handler function so I don't know what the caveats can be, if any.

@YourCommonSense During development, I use a very comprehensive logging system for Laravel, but I would like to develop my own logging system to replace the other one later, because it slows down the application considerably. During development, however, it would be helpful if both were active.
